# htaccess convert 2nd level hostname to parameter

Tags: .htaccess

I want to convert 2nd level domain name to some url parameter using htaccess file like this:

```
us.mydomain.com
```

TO

```
mydomain.com/?country=us
```

What I want is make the convert first and then apply the current rule. Here is my current htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Can anyone help me on the htaccess rule?
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear how you want to combine the existing and the desired rewriting. Odes that get argument (`countr=us`) have to be added to _all_ requests or just to a first one so that it can be stored in an internal session?

Comment: I want to convert all request that match [country].mydomain.com

Comment: Sure, you already said so. But that does not answer my question...

Comment: Hi arkascha, still did not get your meaning, let me make this more easy, the PHP  does not care which domain requested, just add the parameter is quite enough for me. [country].mydomain.com to [country].mydomain.com?country=[country]

Comment: First, convert 2nd domain to parameter and then apply the current rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be easier to evaluate the `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` variable in php for this, but maybe this is what you are looking for on the level of the http server:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Append host name as country argument
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^country=
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?country=%1 [QSA]
```

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: You are right, it is better to use PHP to handle the host thing, anyway I did learned how to write rules in htaccess file according to your example. Thanks a lot!